# HeidiSQL как бороться с окошком типа автокомплит

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Окошко с HeidiSQL]

иногда сам вылазит, когда пишу запрос и все, по всем рабочим столам это окошко, жму esc или кликаю на него - перекидывает на раб. стол с HeidiSQL и иногда ошибка приложения или приходится самому перезапускать HeidiSQL. Писал когда-то разработчику — ответил, что это интерфейс такой используется.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить HeidiSQL в режиме совместимости с WinXP, например

Comment: Нет, минимум Vista